# Left join on doc-uri in MarkLogic Optic query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-11, marklogic-optic-api

I try to do a join with `fragmentColId` to obtain the document uri, but in such a way that it won't drop the row if there is no actual fragment.

I am using [`op:join-doc-uri`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:join-doc-uri), which works fine against TDEs, but not against built-in tables like sys.sys_tables. It would be great if there is a way to write one query that works for both cases.

Comment: I'm intrigued. Can you give a full example?   A few odd things I had to do in the past related to that was to inject some content into op:from-literals() but that was for a small set of supporting data

Comment: What do you mean with a full example? Code? The idea is that I'd like to be able to point to a random view, and list records from it, and blend in the db uri if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the sys.sys_tables table does not come from any document in the database, so it doesn't have a fragment associated with any of it's rows.

If you want to alter your query based on the presence or absence of columns, you probably want to use [op:column-info()](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:column-info) to look at the Optic plan built so far and figure out what columns it returns.

Comment: Yes, I know. Can you think of a way to join with doc-uri in such a way it doesn't drop rows for such tables, but merely adds a null for those?

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/op:join-left-outer ?

Comment: op:column:info() seems useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the left-join first. It looked like this:

```
xquery version '1.0-ml';

import module namespace op = http://marklogic.com/optic at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

declare option xdmp:mapping 'false';

let $fragId := "fragmentId"
let $fragCol := op:fragment-id-col($fragId)
let $schema := "MySchema"
let $view := "MyView"
return
  op:from-view($schema, $view, '', $fragCol)
  =>op:offset-limit(1,10)
  =>op:join-left-outer(
    op:from-search(cts:true-query(), $fragId)
    =>op:join-doc-uri('_dburi', $fragCol)
    =>op:select(($fragId, '_dburi'))
  )
  =>op:result()
```

It is (much) slower than doing a straight `op:join-doc-uri`, and unfortunately, it never completed for schema `sys` and view `sys_tables`.

However, you can analyse the situation first, and either optionally blend in the `op:join-doc-uri`, or write the optic query twice, once with and once without the `op:join-doc-uri`.

I already added an `if` for schema equal to `sys` and `sysspatial`, but resolving this fully dynamically is more elegant. The `op:column-info` suggested by John helps a lot!

```
xquery version '1.0-ml';

import module namespace op = http://marklogic.com/optic at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

declare option xdmp:mapping 'false';

let $fragId := "fragmentId"
let $fragCol := op:fragment-id-col($fragId)
let $schema := "sys"
let $view := "sys_tables"

let $hasFragments :=
  (
    op:from-view($schema, $view, '', $fragCol)
    =>op:column-info()
  ) ! map:get(., 'column') = $fragId

return
  if ($hasFragments) then
    op:from-view($schema, $view, '', $fragCol)
    =>op:offset-limit(1,10)
    =>op:join-doc-uri('_dburi', $fragCol)
    =>op:result()
  else
    op:from-view($schema, $view, '', $fragCol)
    =>op:offset-limit(1,10)
    =>op:result()
```